# Node Promise - Create Validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm trying to write some of my own validation. I've got a controller that will call several of these functions in another file. I have things like name and email.

I'm having a hard time understanding how to return a clean item or an error message. I'd like to use a promise or async-await on this but I'm running into errors.

Would be something like this

----- VALIDATE FILE

```
module.exports.sanitizeName = (name) => {
  if(name === '' || name === null || name === undefined) {
    return new Error('Name is required and cannot be null or undefined)
  } else {
    let cleanedName = name.toLowerCase();

    return cleanedName;
  }
```

----- CONTROLLER

```
const create = async (req, res) => {

  let name = req.body.name;
  let sanitizedName = sanitizeName(name);

  // It's here that I'll need to check for an error object or the cleaned name.
  // Then res.status(201).json the result or res.status(500).json the error
```

originally I tried a promise and ket getting unhandled errors:

```
--- sanitize file
let sanitizeName = (name) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if(happy path) {
    resolve happy path (name)
  } else {
  reject(Error('Name is required and can't be null));
})

--- controller file

let sanitizedName = sanitizeName(name).then((result) => {
  // do something here with result
}).catch((error) => {
  res.status(500).json({
    error_message: error
)}
```

Essentially I'd like to call some functions in another file and have them return a clean version of the input or an error message for validation failures.

I know express-validator and JOI exist. But I'm trying to stay away from libraries and write most of my own code.

Comment: What are you actually asking? How to make this work wth async/await?

Comment: Hard to discern the actual question here...

Comment: Just use `try`/`catch`? Not sure what the problem is. The code of your controller looks incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Validation Class
module.exports.sanitizeName = (name) => {
  if(name === '' || name === null || name === undefined) {
    throw new Error('Name is required and cannot be null or undefined')
  } else {
    let cleanedName = name.toLowerCase();
    return cleanedName;
  }
}
```

// controller file

```
const create = async (req, res) => {
    const response = {data: null, message: null, statusCode: 200}

   try {
    let name = req.body.name;
    response.data = sanitizeName(name);
    
    }catch (e) {
        response.statusCode = 500;
        response.message = e.message;
    }
    return res.status(response.statusCode).json(response); 
}
```